# Python struct unknown size

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I'm implementing a protocol in Python so that one program sends data to another one. It gets the data using structs. I have trouble understanding how to use pack and unpack when the sender decides to send messages in different sizes. How will the receiver know not to initialize the struct before it uses `unpack` on it, when it doesn't know what size the data in the package received is?
In the sender side I have:

```
values = (numOfPackage, data)
st = struct.Struct('I 502s')
packed_data = st.pack(*values)
```

and the receiver side does:

```
packed_data = s.recv(506)
while packed_data != "":
       st = struct.Struct('I 502s')
       unpacked_data = st.unpack(packed_data)
       print unpacked_data[1]
       packed_data = s.recv(506)
```

but then I want to send a shorter message like "I finished" from the sender to the receiver.. but how will the receiver know not to do  `st = struct.Struct('I 502s')` because it's actually 10s and not 502s?

Answer (score 0):

Since the amount received is the same each time, you can just slice down after determining the real length:

```
st = struct.Struct('I 502s')
packed_data = s.recv(st.size)
while packed_data:
    length, data = st.unpack(packed_data)
    data = data[:length]
    print data
    packed_data = s.recv(st.size)
```

Alternatively, use a shorter `Struct` to parse the length only, then manually slice out the bit your care about:

```
st = struct.Struct('I')
packed_data = s.recv(506)
while packed_data:
    length, = st.unpack_from(packed_data)  # Ignores trailing data using unpack_from
    data = packed_data[st.size:st.size+length]
    print data
    packed_data = s.recv(506)
```

Comment: I tried your first solution but it's still problematic..I did:

    ' st = struct.Struct('I I 502s')
    packed_data = s.recv(st.size)
    while packed_data != "":
                pckNum, length, data = st.unpack(packed_data)
                data = data[:length]
               print data
               packed_data = s.recv(st.size) ' 
and it says:
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 510
when I try sending a shorter message

Comment: @Shirli: Why are you using `I I 502s` as the format? Your original post said the format was `I 502s`. If you're using my first solution, the format of the send and receive `Struct`s should be the same; even when only sending `"I finished"` it would still send 506 bytes, and the receiver would receive all of them, then slice down to just the number of meaningful bytes sent.

Comment: @Shirli: Side-note: If the `Struct` size is never changing, don't create it in your loop; generate it once outside the loop, and reuse it. If you're recreating it every time, you may as well skip using `Struct` and just use the module level functions; the only advantage to `struct.Struct` is that it creates and caches `Struct` objects for you on demand; creating them by hand every use is the slowest possible solution (since it bypasses the `Struct` cache used by module level functions).

Comment: But from what I understood you meant that the first int will be used for writing the length of the packet into the first 4 bytes of the packet itself.. Am I wrong? That's why I added another int..

Comment: @Shirli: Weren't you already sending the length? Seems silly/redundant to send the length of the length + data, then the length of the data. You were already sending 506 bytes unconditionally, this doesn't change that. It just gives you trims down to the "real" data instead of working with data+padding.

Comment: I'm sorry for still not understanding it... But then where is the length saved in your solution?...

Comment: @Shirli: In the variable named `length`. You always receive 506 bytes, but you unpack the first four to figure out how much of the remaining 502 are "real" vs. padding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98610/discussion-between-shirli-and-shadowranger).